# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler Element Name is dynamic

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I tried to write some code in JMeter WebDriver from Chrome. And I find the ID Name is dynamic. When reload the Chrome Browser, the name will be changed

Ex:
1st Load:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[@id='dropdown-menu-2724']/li")).click();
```

2nd Load:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[@id='dropdown-menu-3607']/li")).click();
```

It will cause the error with Element not found messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no other way of uniquely identify the element by other means (text, parent, child, whatever) you can use XPath [contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) to do a partial match on the selector.

Something like:

```
//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li
```

You might also find [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article useful.

Comment: Thanks DT. I have changed the code and hit another error. Do I need to import the XPath  library as well? Can you please also advise? WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).click();   Error & Response Code 500: "javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

Comment: Hi, I found out if I hardcode the variable, it will accept. WDS.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='dropdown-menu-7773']/li")).click(); but if I using this variable, it will not click. ("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")) can you please advise?